# Cygwin X start up config file location

Tags: cygwin, xterm

I can't find the config file I need to modify for my install of Xwin via Cygwin.

Currently when X loads it fires off and Xterm window.  Essentially all I want to do is comment out/delete this line so I have a server running in the background and I can use some shotcuts I have set up/terminal commands as needed for the apps.

Comment: No idea, but the best place for Cygwin/X questions is the cygwin-xfree mailing list.

Comment: Check out andLinux http://www.andlinux.org/ for what I think is a much improved and less painful Cygwin.

Answer (score 0):

[You may create a ~/.startxwinrc script to customize the client programs started, rather than a single xterm.](http://x.cygwin.com/docs/ug/using.html)